# Sistema de login que no funciona en Microsoft Edge

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código de un sistema de login que si funciona en Google Chrome y Firefox pero no funciona en Microsoft Edge;

Simplemente me lleva al index sin hacer login y aun reintentado no funciona, no me arroja ninguna excepcion.

```
    <?php


include( "conexion.php" );
$tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies = time()+50400;
$autenticado = false;

if ( isset( $_POST[ 'datos_usuario' ] ) ) { 
    include('include/funciones.php');
    getListadoUsuarios();   

    setcookie( "intento_login", "1", time() + 60 ); //si el usuario llego aqui pulsando el boton de login creara esta cookie para saber si fallo el intento de  inicio de sesion.

    try {

        $usuario = htmlentities( addslashes( $_POST[ "usuario" ] ) );
        $password = htmlentities( addslashes( $_POST[ "clave_usuario" ] ) );

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos_usuarios WHERE Nombre_usuario =:nombre_usuario";

        $resultado = $base->prepare( $sql );

        $resultado->execute( array( ":nombre_usuario" => $usuario ) );

        while ( $registro = $resultado->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {

            if ( password_verify( $password, $registro[ "Clave_usuario" ] ) ) {
                $sector_usuario = $registro['Sector_usuario'];
                $nivel_usuario = $registro['Nivel_usuario'];
                $oficina_usuario = $registro['Oficina'];
                $nombre_apellido = $registro['Nombre_apellido'];
                $celular = $registro['Celular'];
                $correo = $registro['mail'];
                setcookie('_idUsr_lgd',$registro["Id"],$tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies);
                setcookie('Sector_usuario',$sector_usuario, $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies);              
                setcookie('Nivel_usuario',$nivel_usuario, $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies);
                setcookie('Oficina_usuario',$oficina_usuario, $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies);
                setcookie('Nombre_apellido',$nombre_apellido, $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies);
                setcookie('Cedular',$celular, $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies);
                setcookie('mail',$correo, $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies);
                $contador = 1; /*Si llego aqui es que se encontro la clave en la base de datos */
            }

        }

        $sesion = 0; //Sesion =0 fallo y si es =1 tuvo exito en iniciar

        $resultado->closeCursor(); //Termina la ejecutacion


        if ( $contador <> 0 ) {

            $sesion = 1;
            setcookie( "nombre_usuario", $usuario, $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies ); //Crea cookie por 24 horas si no se ha selecionado checkbox  
            $autenticado = true;

            /*  Almacena todos los usuarios y el numero de los mismos en dos cookies */
                $usuarios = $base->query( "SELECT * FROM datos_usuarios WHERE Nivel_usuario <> 'Solicitante' " )->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

                $posicion = 0;
                foreach ( $usuarios as $registrados ) {
                    $usuarios_registrados[ $posicion ] = $registrados->Nombre_usuario;
                    $posicion++;
                }

                /* Guarda la cantidad de usuarios existentes en una cookie */
                setcookie( 'numero_usuarios', ( $posicion - 1 ), $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies );
                /* Guardar los nombre de los usuarios existentes en una cookie */
                setcookie( 'listado_usuarios', serialize( $usuarios_registrados ), $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies );              

                /* FIN Almacena todos los usuarios y el numero de los mismos en dos cookies */

                $token = mt_rand(1,99999);

                $sql_Token="UPDATE datos_usuarios SET Token=:eToken WHERE Nombre_usuario=:eUsuario";

                $resultado=$base->prepare($sql_Token);

                $resultado->execute(array( ":eUsuario"=>$usuario, ":eToken"=>$token));

                setcookie("token_usuario", $token,$tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies );

            //EVALUA SI SE HA SELECIONADO EL CHECKBOX

            if ( isset( $_POST[ "recordar" ] ) ) {
                setcookie( "nombre_usuario", $usuario, $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies ); //Crea cookie por 1 semana si se ha selecionado checkbox 
                //Crea la cookie y almacena el nombre del usuario para ser rescatado mas luego
                setcookie("token_usuario", $token, $tiempo_vencimiento_sesiones_cookies ); 
            }
        } else {
            header( "location:login.php" );

        }
        if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ "nombre_usuario" ] ) ) {

            header( "location:creacion_solicitudes.php" );
        }

    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo "La linea del error es: " . $e->getMessage() . " " . $e->getLine();

    }

}


?>
```

Comment: que te dice la cabecera en la consola?

Comment: @aldanux ahi esta una captura de lo que me indica la consola http://prntscr.com/hjf6u1

Comment: Me he referido a la cabecera HTTP que lo puedes ver en el tab `Red`

Comment: @aldanux Disculpa, esta es http://prntscr.com/hjfxca

Comment: Prueba con una ruta absoluta: `header('Location: http://localhost:8080/ps_bdi/login.php');`